# The image is not appearing as a style for the list why?

Tags: html, css

The image is not appearing can anyone tell me why?

```
ul li {
background-image: url(logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 0px; 
}
```

This is what appears

[image]

this is what i need

[image]

Comment: Does `logo.png` exist near of your CSS file? If they're not in the same directory, use `../` to go UP one level in the directory tree.

Comment: yes i checked many times even the spelling

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to add quotes:

`background-image: url('logo.png');`

Comment: IS your unordered list inside certain div or smth like that

Comment: Then try this one more time `background-image: url(../logo.png);`

Comment: @ gibsonman507 still not working

Comment: Are you trying to actually set a `background-image` to the list or an image individually for each item?

Comment: Bhumin Vadalia yes I've tried #div .ul li but that is not working either

Comment: Remember that urls in CSS navigate from the directory that your _stylesheet_ is in. If the image is in /images. You need to nagivate: ../images/logo.png

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: In Chrome, press F12, open Network tab, refresh the page and look for 404 errors.

Comment: I would have shown exactly what i needed if i could post images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the file path correct is the key, as it has been pointed out to me in the comments that for file paths without special characters the quotes are not mandatory.

This is mainly the code you have supplied, I've only changed the image (SO won't let me post the fiddle without some code, so that's why I'm putting it here).

```
ul li {
background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/polyglot-404.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 0px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ray8z48b/

If you include the above CSS in your HTML file between  tags, than the logo.png has to be relative to the path of the HTML file.

If you link to a CSS file in a different directory, the logo.png has to be relative to that path.

For example, if I'd build a site, I'd have the root directory with all the HTML files, two folders (at least) one called "img" and one called "css".

So in the first case it would be `"./img/logo.png"` or `img/logo.png` in the latter it would be `"../img/logo.png"`.

Comment: Again: Using quotes is pointless unless you have special characters in your URL such as white spaces, parenthesis, single/double quotes.

Comment: You don't `need` to use quotes in the file path. The path can also can be relative or absolute.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it's not necessary, have always used them.

Answer (score -2):

I think about your problem. I have one solution.
Here your Html file and your image in same folder,ohterwise you give path of logo.png in double quotes

```
    ul li {
background-image: url("logo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 0px; 
}
```

I think it help you

Comment: Using quotes is pointless unless you have special characters in your URL.